# Can you set a min/max value to hours in oracle apexs(19.1) date picker?

Tags: datepicker, oracle-apex

Hey can you set a minumum / maximum value to hours on the date picker in oracle apex(19.1)? F.e i want only display values from 8am to 4pm independent of the date in the front end with the date picker( and time picker).  Didn't found any solution so far.
[datePicker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgWDe.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, with the current latest version of APEX (20.1), there is no way to limit the hours/minutes that can be chosen in the date picker.  It can only be limited by day/week/month/year. Maybe it will be available in [APEX 20.2](https://apex.oracle.com/en/learn/resources/sod/) since they plan on utilizing the Oracle JET Date and Time picker.